# OpenApi generator case insensitive configuration for enum deserialization

Tags: java, spring, enums, openapi, openapi-generator

In our project we use openapi-generator-maven-plugin version 4.3.1 with generator name - spring.

We created enum type as request body parameter:

```
channel:
      type: string
      enum: [MANUAL, AUTO]
      example: MANUAL, AUTO
```

OpenAPI generator generated next deserealizer for this enum

```
@JsonCreator
public static ChannelEnum fromValue(String value) {
  for (ChannelEnum b : ChannelEnum.values()) {
    if (b.value.equals(value)) {
      return b;
    }
  }
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value '" + value + "'");
}
```

For 'auto' it will throw IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value 'auto'").

Is it possible to configurate OpenAPI generatot to handle string in lowercase as enums as well?

Comment: Please open an issue via http://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/new so that the openapi-generator community can help you out.

Comment: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/8084 I created